# How to strictly prove that $x - 1 = (y - 5)^2$ will have same vertices and foci with $y^2 = x$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Disclaimer: this is a noob question, I know.

Today that question was in a class and nobody solved it :P So, can somebody provide a little of this basic knowledge?

Comment: it doesn't, one parabola is a translation of the other parabola.  The vertex and and focus have both moved over 1 and up 5.

Comment: Maybe you should recheck the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't have same vertices and foci. 
If you compare these equations with $(y-k)^2$ $=$ $4a(x-h)$, then the first one has vertex $(1, 5)$ and focus $(5/4, 5)$ but the 2nd equation has vertex $(0, 0)$ and focus $(1/4, 0)$.